# Percentage rate of showing for random embed message in discord.py

Tags: discord.py

Im new to discord.py and im trying to make a gacha bot where it has SR, SSR, and UR rolls in it and i want to divide them into a different chances of showing when someone type the command. For the SR or 3 star is 94.3 %, the SSR or 4 star is 5.1 %, and the UR or 5 star is 0.6 %.

Heres the code.

```html
@client.command()
@commands.cooldown(1, 4, commands.BucketType.user)
async def wish(ctx):
    items = [
    discord.Embed(title = "Wish Successfull", description = "You get 3 :star: Ebony Bow <:EbonyBow:857220938571317248> (Bow Weapon).", color = ctx.author.color), 
    discord.Embed(title = "Wish Successfull", description = "You get 3 :star: Raven Bow <:RavenBow:857221178338574357> (Bow Weapon).", color = ctx.author.color),
    discord.Embed(title = "Wish Successfull", description = "You get 3 :star: Recurve Bow <:RecurveBow:857221810932547594> (Bow Weapon).", color = ctx.author.color),
    discord.Embed(title = "Wish Successfull", description = "You get 4 :star: Alley Hunter <:AlleyHunter:857262273805287434> (Bow Weapon).", color = ctx.author.color), 
    discord.Embed(title = "Wish Successfull", description = "You get 4 :star: Blackcliff Warbow <:BlackcliffWarbow:857262272656441345> (Bow Weapon).", color = ctx.author.color),
    discord.Embed(title = "Wish Successfull", description = "You get 4 :star: Compound Bow <:CompoundBow:857262272622493736> (Bow Weapon).", color = ctx.author.color),
    discord.Embed(title = "Wish Successfull", description = "You get 5 :star: Lost Prayer to the Sacred Winds <:LostPrayertotheSacredWinds:857281184492552213> (Catalyst Weapon).", color = ctx.author.color),
    discord.Embed(title = "Wish Successfull", description = "You get 5 :star: Memory of Dust <:MemoryofDust:857281131413635122> (Catalyst Weapon).", color = ctx.author.color),
    discord.Embed(title = "Wish Successfull", description = "You get 5 :star: Skyward Atlas <:SkywardAtlas:857281156763746364> (Catalyst Weapon).", color = ctx.author.color)]
    randomitem = random.choice(items)
    await ctx.send(embed=randomitem)
```

Answer (score 1):

As the previous answer says, it says that `all have the same chance of being sent.` Since I look at the code, I decided to make it cleaner to make it more readable :D.

the code :

```py
@client.command()
@commands.cooldown(1, 4, commands.BucketType.user)
async def wish(ctx):
    items = [
      "3 :star: Ebony Bow <:EbonyBow:857220938571317248> (Bow Weapon)",
      "3 :star: Raven Bow <:RavenBow:857221178338574357> (Bow Weapon).",
      "3 :star: Recurve Bow <:RecurveBow:857221810932547594> (Bow Weapon)",
      "4 :star: Alley Hunter <:AlleyHunter:857262273805287434> (Bow Weapon).",
      "4 :star: Blackcliff Warbow <:BlackcliffWarbow:857262272656441345> (Bow Weapon).",
      "4 :star: Compound Bow <:CompoundBow:857262272622493736> (Bow Weapon).",
      "5 :star: Lost Prayer to the Sacred Winds <:LostPrayertotheSacredWinds:857281184492552213> (Catalyst Weapon).",
      "5 :star: Memory of Dust <:MemoryofDust:857281131413635122> (Catalyst Weapon).",
      "5 :star: Skyward Atlas <:SkywardAtlas:857281156763746364> (Catalyst Weapon)."
    ]
    randomitem = discord.Embed(title = "Wish Successfull", description = f"You get {random.choice(items)}", color = ctx.author.color)]
    await ctx.send(embed=randomitem)
```

Answer (score 0):

They all have the same chance of being sent.

You could add more of the same item in the list to make it more common. But a better way would be to assign them a percentage in a database and then make a function to send one based on those chances.